# Re-arranging matrices/vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

If I have an equation $$r_1(r_1a+r_2b+r_3c)+r_2(r_1b+r_2d+r_3e)+r_3(r_1c+r_2e+r_3f)=1$$ where all $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are variables and $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are constants. I want to re-arrange them such that $VC=1$ where $V$ is a variable matrix and $C$ is a $6$x$1$ constant vector. How do I approach this problem ?

Comment: Your equation is not linear. It contains squares and products of variables. I don't see how this could be transformed in a linear equation. Check how a product of a matrix and a vector can result in a scalar $1$.

Comment: Collect all terms multiplying the constants $a,b,c,f,e,f$, i.e. $r_1^2 a + (r_1r_2 + r_2t_1)b + \dots = 1$. Then this is becomes a scalar product of a constant vector and a vector that depends on the variables $r_1,r_2,r_3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you've written this slightly backwards, and meant to say that the variables were $a$ through $e$, since as @Axel notes, it cannot be done otherwise:

Expand everything: 
$$ 
r_1 r_1 a + r_1 r_2 b + r_1 r_3 c + r_2 r_1 b + r_2 r_2 d + r_2 r_3 e + r_3 r_1 c + r_3 r_2 e + r_3 r_3 f = 1
$$
Now write the coefficients of your unknowns $a, \ldots, f$ as a vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
r_1 r_1 & r_1 r_2 +  r_2 r_1 & r_1 r_3 + r_3 r_1  & r_2 r_2 &  r_2 r_3 + r_3 r_2 & r_3 r_3 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f
\end{bmatrix}
= 1
$$

(You may need to transpose both sides to get the form you want).

Comment: Yeah sorry a through f are the variables. Thank you for the answer